# Make invisible a field when one of the options is true in Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to make invisible a field if one of those options are true, I don't know if this is possible.
I try:

```
<field name="x_field1" string="something" attrs="{'invisible': [('x_field2','!=','value'),'|',('x_field3','=','value'),'|',('x_field4','=','value')]}"/>
```

And this:

```
<field name="x_field1" string="something" attrs="{'invisible': ['|',('x_field2','!=','value'),('x_field3','=','value'),('x_field4','=','value')]}"/>
```

Without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Odoo [Domains](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/developer/reference/orm.html#domains) documentation:

> '|'
> logical OR, arity 2.

You have three options, so you need to use two `|` operators, like the following:

```
['|', '|', ('x_field2', '!=', 'value'), ('x_field3', '=', 'value'), ('x_field4', '=', 'value')]
```